Exporting TSIBBLE object to CSV (forecasted values with prediction intervals)
I would like to export to CSV the results of my forecast project, summarised by following tsibble object
# A tsibble: 7 x 6 [1M]
# Key:       .model [1]
  .model                             Month           Fatturati    .mean                  `80%`                  `95%`
  <chr>                              <mth>              <dist>    <dbl>                 <hilo>                 <hilo>
1 ARIMA(Fatturati ~ pdq(0, 0, 0)) 2024 giu N(5545322, 6.6e+11) 5545322. [4507218.0, 6583426]80 [3957678.9, 7132965]95
2 ARIMA(Fatturati ~ pdq(0, 0, 0)) 2024 lug N(3818923, 6.6e+11) 3818923. [2780819.4, 4857027]80 [2231280.3, 5406567]95
3 ARIMA(Fatturati ~ pdq(0, 0, 0)) 2024 ago   N(2e+06, 6.6e+11) 2009116. [ 971011.8, 3047220]80 [ 421472.7, 3596759]95
4 ARIMA(Fatturati ~ pdq(0, 0, 0)) 2024 set N(4281658, 6.6e+11) 4281658. [3243553.6, 5319762]80 [2694014.5, 5869301]95
5 ARIMA(Fatturati ~ pdq(0, 0, 0)) 2024 ott N(4152656, 6.6e+11) 4152656. [3114552.2, 5190760]80 [2565013.1, 5740299]95
6 ARIMA(Fatturati ~ pdq(0, 0, 0)) 2024 nov N(3054704, 6.6e+11) 3054704. [2016600.2, 4092808]80 [1467061.1, 4642347]95
7 ARIMA(Fatturati ~ pdq(0, 0, 0)) 2024 dic N(3399502, 6.6e+11) 3399502. [2361398.2, 4437606]80 [1811859.1, 4987145]95

I would like to carry further analysis in Excel and the build some reports from there.
The problem is that I am unable to find a solution.
Any help?
Thank you in advance
Mark

Hi Mark_. A tsibble can be written to a CSV file using the same methods as a tibble. Example: readr::write_csv(mytsibble, file = "mytsibble.csv")

Further, the distribution's parameters can be pulled out with distributional::parameters() and the upper and lower bounds for the interval can be obtained with 80%$upper and 80%$lower.

@MitchellO'Hara-Wild After computing my forecasts , I tried to extract both upper and lower bounds, together with the Level, but it didn't work. fc_hilo <- hilo(fc,level=c(80,95))  `

fc_hilo$lower
NULL
Messaggio di avvertimento:
Unknown or uninitialised column: lower.
fc_hilo$upper
NULL
Messaggio di avvertimento:
Unknown or uninitialised column: upper.
fc_hilo$level
NULL
Messaggio di avvertimento:
Unknown or uninitialised column: level. `


@Seth your suggestion worked out like a charm. Thank you so much!

@Mark_: You can find the documentation for how to extract quantities from a hilo here: http://pkg.mitchelloharawild.com/distributional/reference/hilo.html
In this case fc_hilo is a dataset, not a hilo. You would do fc_hilo |> mutate(`80%`$lower, `80%`$upper)

@MitchellO'Hara-Wild it perfectly works. thanks a lot for your help
